# Reach out to Breeze.js about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, outsourcing

I ran into this question - likely will be 10k only - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919279/breeze-sharp-roadmap

[Breeze.js's support page](http://www.breezejs.com/support) has a link to [breeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/breeze). It isn't giving much guidance on what to ask or how to ask within the context of our on-topic guidelines.

Comment: Question closed, with the help of a moderator.

Comment: Questions about how to use breeze.js should be fine, questions about the product itself (meta questions), we should not handle. No one other than the developers knows the product's roadmap. I perfectly agree with your close reason.

Comment: Should [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739967/breeze-roadmap) be deleted thus ? It has been closed as off-topic, and it is clearly, however it has upvotes so I cannot vote to delete it.

Comment: @gunr2171: What about the fact that one of the developers answered it?

Comment: *Free! All Breeze packages provide access to: (...) StackOverflow.* Wow, that is very nice of them, providing free access to StackOverflow to all of their customers. Sounds like a good reason to get me one of those packages, whatever they are...